# ArrayIndex out of bound in java byte[]

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

Can any body resolve this.

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     byte[] temp = "smile".getBytes();
     byte[] hash = new byte[32];
     System.arraycopy(temp, 0, hash, 0, 16);
     System.arraycopy(temp, 0, hash, 15, 16);
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to print the length of `temp` array? Also see stacktrace at which line error is produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

length of temp is `5` and you are trying to copy to hash for `length` `16` which is throwing Exception.

```
System.arraycopy(source, sourcePosition, destination, destinationPosition, length);
```

> Copies an array from the specified source array, ***beginning*** at the
>   **specified position**, ***to the*** specified position of the destination
>   array. A subsequence of array components are copied from the source
>   array referenced by src to the destination array referenced by dest.
>   The number of ***components copied is equal to the length argument***.

Your source array must have 16 components to copy but here length is 5 and you are trying to copy 16 components from `temp`.
You can increase your `temp` array (i.e  `byte[] temp = "smile is the most important thing.".getBytes();`).

Answer (score 2):

As per javadoc on System.arraycopy :
If any of the following is true, an IndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown and the destination is not modified:

- The srcPos argument is negative.
- The destPos argument is negative.
- The length argument is negative.
- srcPos+length is greater than src.length, the length of the source array.
- destPos+length is greater than dest.length, the length of the destination array.

PFB code snippet:

```
    byte[] temp = "smile".getBytes();
    byte[] hash = new byte[32];

    System.arraycopy(temp, 0, hash, 0, temp.length);
    // System.arraycopy(temp, 0, hash, 15, 16); // should be used carefully
```